# Motivation behind the definition of "Relation" concept in C++20

Tags: c++, std, c++20, c++-concepts

Both [the online C++ draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/concept.relation) and [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/Relation) define the standard `Relation` concept like this:

```
template <class R, class T, class U>
concept Relation =
  std::Predicate<R, T, T> && std::Predicate<R, U, U> &&
  std::Predicate<R, T, U> && std::Predicate<R, U, T>;
```

This definition surprises me, since I would expect to see something like

```
template <class R, class T, class U>
concept Relation = std::Predicate<R, T, U>;
```

or probably

```
template <class R, class T, class U>
concept Relation = std::Predicate<R, T, U> && std::Predicate<R, U, T>;
```

or even

```
template <class R, class T, class U>
concept Relation = std::Predicate<R, T, U> || std::Predicate<R, U, T>;
```

From my understanding, a [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) between types `T` and `U` is a binary predicate on pairs `(T, U)`. Thus, it **makes no sense** to evaluate a relation on two objects of type `T` or two objects of type `U`. However, the given definition requires that a relation should be callable with arguments `(T,T)` and `(U,U)`.

***My question is***: what is the motivation behind this (seemingly wrong) definition of a `Relation` concept?

The explanation given on cppreference states that

> The concept Relation specifies that R defines a binary relation over the set of expressions whose type and value category are those encoded by ***either T or U***.

*(emphasis mine)*

This sounds weird to me: why the general `Relation` concept is defined two support arguments of ***two types*** used in ***any combination***?

One possibility may be that this concept is used for comparison of pointers and `nullptr_t`, and for comparison of iterators and sentinel iterators. If this is the case, why is this concept called a `Relation`, and not something more specific, like, say, `InterComparable`? Is it just a misnomer?

Comment: fwiw, the explanation on cppref fits the definition quite well "R defines a binary relation over the set of expressions whose type and value category are those encoded by **either** T or U.", though I agree that its a strange way of defining a binary relation

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Yep, I've seen this phrase, thank you. This, however, doesn't explain why there are ***two*** types, each representing a possible argument type. Why not a single type? Why not, say, seventeen types? The set of possible argument types does not seem to be connected in any way to the number of arguments. I'll update the question, thank you.

Comment: I would say it is just a misnomer. `Predicate` is already the relation you expect. `Relation` allows to extend the set of types so `Relation<R, A, B>` might be read as `Predicate<R, A U B, A U B>` (with U as union for set).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a misnomer. As far as I can tell, it exists to provide the syntactic requirements for things like [*StrictWeakOrder*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/StrictWeakOrder), without the semantic requirements.

E.g. consider also

```
template <class R, class T, class U>
concept Equivalence = std::Relation<R, T, U>;

//A relation r is an equivalence if
// - it is reflexive: for all x, r(x, x) is true;
// - it is symmetric: for all a and b, if r(a, b) is true then r(b, a) is true;
// - it is transitive: for all a, b and c, if r(a, b) and r(b, c) are both true then r(a, c) is true;
```

Comment: `Relation` is used in more places than just as a building block to `StrictWeakOrder`. If that were the case, it wouldn't be necessary.